# distict cant use in this

Tags: sql, mariadb, distinct

I want to display my data without duplication in any of the columns,

I use distinct or group by tetep it doesn't work

**my sql :**

```sql
SELECT DISTINCT rl.NIK,date(rl.enroll),LEFT(TIME(rl.enroll),8) AS time
FROM RTattandenceLog rl, mstEmp e
WHERE DATE(rl.enroll)=CURDATE()-1 AND e.idDept=3 AND e.NIK=rl.NIK
```

**this is resultc:** 
[image]

**the lines I crossed should not be displayed**

Comment: if you include time in your `distinct` things like this could happen. What time do you prefer ¿newest or oldest?

Comment: Which row do you want to keep, the row with `08:13:37` or with `17:16:57`. Adding `GROUP BY 1,2` wil make sure the first two columns are unique, then change last column to `min(LEFT(TIME(rl.enroll),8))` or `max(LEFT(TIME(rl.enroll),8))`.

Comment: @JaimeDrq what I apply is the earliest time

Comment: @Luuk I have used Min and an error occurs

Comment: It is always easy to solve 'an error occurs'.....

Answer (score 2):

Basically, you want an aggregation query with `JOIN`.  I'm not sure why you are separating out the date/time into two columns instead of just using:

```
SELECT rl.NIK, DATE(rl.enroll),
       CAST(MIN(TIME(rl.enroll)) as CHAR)
FROM RTattandenceLog rl JOIN
     mstEmp e
     ON e.NIK = rl.NIK
WHERE rl.enroll < CURDATE() AND
      rl.enroll >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      e.idDept = 3 
GROUP BY rl.NIK, DATE(rl.enroll);
```

Notes:

- This uses proper, explicit, **standard**, readable `JOIN` syntax.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.
- The date comparisons do not use `DATE()`.  That makes it this more compatible with indexes and helps the optimizer.
- There is no implicit conversion of a `time` value into a string.  Not sure why a time is not good enough (`date` seems to be), but this explicitly converts to a string.  Implicit conversions are the cause of both semantic errors and performance problems.

I don't understand why you would want to split the date and time into separate columns.  Perhaps this is sufficient:

```
SELECT rl.NIK, MIN(rl.enroll)
FROM RTattandenceLog rl JOIN
     mstEmp e
     ON e.NIK = rl.NIK
WHERE rl.enroll < CURDATE() AND
      rl.enroll >= CURDATE() - INTERVAL 1 DAY AND
      e.idDept = 3 
GROUP BY rl.NIK, DATE(rl.enroll);
```

Comment: Great answer. And very complete. :) By the way, would there be any notable difference here between `MIN(TIME(rl.enroll))` and `TIME(MIN(rl.enroll))`?

Comment: @BartHofland . . . I imagine that the difference would be hard to measure.  On the one hand, `datetime` values are 8 bytes and `time`s are 3 bytes, so converting before hand is a bit less data.  But there is overhead to the conversion.

Answer (score -1):

Don't you actually want to create groups here based on the NIK and the enroll date? And show the earliest time for every group?

Something like this:

```sql
SELECT rl.NIK, date(rl.enroll), LEFT(TIME(MIN(rl.enroll)), 8) AS time
FROM RTattandenceLog rl, mstEmp e
WHERE DATE(rl.enroll) = CURDATE() - 1 AND e.idDept = 3 AND e.NIK = rl.NIK
GROUP BY rl.NIK, date(rl.enroll)
```

I do not use MariaDB myself, so I cannot test it. But it's pretty standard SQL syntax, so I assume it should work.

Comment: Not that standard to forget a field of the select using a group by function. Your query, apart from won't work, when fixed, will return duplicates

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . Hmmm. I don't think I forgot a field of the SELECT-clause in the GROUP BY clause. I tested it in Microsoft SQL Server with stand-in test tables (albeit with a slightly different syntax, since it does not support the MySQL/MariaDB functions of your original query). It works just fine. So I don't think my query is the problem here.

Comment: You were right, I didn't see the `MIN` in your time field.

Comment: @JaimeDrq . . . Ah, OK. Yes, it is indeed quickly overlooked when it's nested in two other function calls. I'm glad you could take another look at it. :) Anyway, since Gordon Linoff posted another excellent and exhaustive answer, I guess this answer of mine has become obsolete now. In my answer, I only changed the most crucial parts of the original query and kept as much of its logic untouched (mainly because I was unable to experiment with alternatives and test it properly).

Comment: I upvoted yours if it helps... (and Gordon's one)